# Are Jaskier's songs inspired from the books or completely original to the Netflix series?

Tags: the-witcher

Throughout the first two series of *The Witcher* we have 6 named songs (3 from each season) that Jaskier sings:

- Toss a Coin to Your Witcher
- The Fishmonger's Daughter
- Her Sweet Kiss
- Burn Butcher Burn
- Whoreson Prison Blues
- The Golden One

I'm just reading through *Sword of Destiny* and in the first short story it's noted that Dandelion sings The Stars above the Path round the campfire. I've not read much further than the first short story here though so don't know if any other named songs appear later on in the books.

Are any of the songs from the first two seasons (or later if/when we get them) inspired by, or named after, songs mentioned in the books?

Comment: It seems unlikely the novels would have a song title with that seems to be a riff on the real-world "Folsom Prison Blues."

Comment: It might be interesting to assemble a list of all songs that _are_ performed/composed by Dandelion in canon, for another question.

Answer (score 2):

I've done quite a bit of looking around and barring any explicit confirmation on this matter I think we can conclude that no, the songs at present are not based off of those in the books.

To start with we have 4 named songs in the books Elaine Ettariel, Elusive, The Stars above the Path and Winter (or The Eternal Fire). The only one that could potentially be similar is Her Sweet Kiss being based off of The Stars above the Path. Both songs are romantic ballads and both are sung by Jaskier during the hunt for the dragon. However, the lyrics to Her Sweet Kiss don't really seem to match the title of The Stars above the Path.

We also know that at least Toss a Coin to Your Witcher was written by Jenny Klein. She took inspiration from the books for the song but not from Jaskier's songs and it doesn't really match any known ones as well.

> Klein turned to Andrzej Sapkowski's stories upon which the Netflix series is based for inspiration in writing the lyrics, which is when she started to notice something pretty big. "Often the Witcher doesn’t get paid for his work. That sucks!" she says. "I was in my car and I was just feeling bad for Geralt not getting paid and that’s when I started to sing to myself, 'Toss a coin to your Witcher.' It was when I was driving and then I pulled over and fumbled with my voice memo to record the lines and then I rushed home instead of going to the errand I was supposed to be running."
>
> She laughs again before continuing, "And I just wrote out the lyrics in like 10 minutes. It just spurted out. It was really fun. I knew I was going to be doing it but the times when I sat down like, okay, I’ve got to write this, of course it comes when you least expect it. I’m glad it did!"
>
> Another source of inspiration is the name of the location in which Geralt's story takes place in episode 2. Translated from an elvish language, Klein says it means "Valley of Flowers or Valley of Plenty." "So I was like, to not even get paid in the Valley of Plenty? Come on! Toss a coin to your Witcher! I got excited about this being a way to draw empathy for the character. So that’s how I ended up coining 'Toss a Coin to Your Witcher.'"
>
> <sub>[Entertainment Weekly, Anatomy of a song: How The Witcher earworm 'Toss a Coin to Your Witcher' was made](https://ew.com/tv/the-witcher-toss-a-coin-to-your-witcher-anatomy-of-a-song/)</sub>

Belousova and Ostinelli have been quite open about their work writing the music for the series and they note that they took inspiration from the scripts. I can't find any information on them having taken inspiration from the books.

> **AF: In terms of scoring the series, were you writing music at the script stage, do you like to work episode to episode? Talk about your process and division of labor.**
>
> **Belousova:** Before we even had a cut to work with, we already had over an hour of music written, which included songs, dances and thematic suites. Having worked in ballet and theater, both Sonya and I are always eager to take inspiration purely from the script and let our imagination drive us. You have a blank canvas in front of you, which you can paint in any color. You’re driven by the music itself, its melody, or harmony with the goal to make the piece as dynamic and entertaining as possible. When writing to picture, you need to be aware at all times of the rules the picture itself sets for you. At the same time, there’s beauty in those limitations as they set very clear guidelines.
>
> **Ostinelli:** Once the picture editors started assembling the cuts, we started scoring to picture. That was around April 2019. Hours of new material had to be written, dances had to be shortened in order to follow the pace of the editing, all the songs that were approved at the demo stage now had to be recorded and finalized. Overall, this was a very elaborate process, which required our involvement for most of the year.
>
> **Belousova:** We wrote and produced over eight hours of original music for the series that included songs, score, folk tunes, and dances. We recorded unique one-of-a-kind historical instruments, many of which were crafted specifically for The Witcher, and personally performed and recorded over sixty instruments on the soundtrack.
>
> <sub>[Awards Focus, Sonya Belousova & Giona Ostinelli On Crafting The Songs & Score for The Witcher](https://awardsfocus.com/interviews/composers/sonya-belousova-giona-ostinelli-interview-composing-for-the-witcher/)</sub>

Lastly, Joey Batey has made some comments on his involvement with the songs. From how he's worded the below it does seem to me that the songs are completely original for the series.

> **You received your first composing credit on the second series of The Witcher. Has composing for the soundtrack deepened your understanding of the characters and world?**
>
> Before starting season two, the composer Joe Trapanese and I met on Zoom and I basically said ‘look, I want to help write the songs, I want to be involved’. I was involved a fair bit in season one, but I wanted to be involved from the get-go on season two. Joe is so open and collaborative. Then the pandemic hit so we suddenly had so much more time to explore these songs. I think we wrote a tonne of versions - we were constantly back and forth with each other trying to work out what song would best suit not only Jaskier's journey and own character development, but to reflect the darker grittier season two. The show is getting darker and stranger, and we wanted to step away from the pop-y, happier bites of season one and actually get into what makes Jaskier tick and what he wants to do as an artist. It's not going to be everyone's ringtone as ‘Toss a Coin to Your Witcher’ was, I think, but I'm proud of the freedom that we were given by the producer Lauren Schmidt Hissrich and the executives to pursue a more three dimensional, more textured character decision.
>
> <sub>[Boys By Girls, Conversations, Joey Batey](https://boysbygirls.co.uk/conversations/joey-batey)</sub>

---

I also want to note that there is at least one other song sung so far. In season 1 Jaskier sings an unnamed song in a tavern:

Answer (score 1):

> The song was created specifically for the TV series, and does not appear in the novels the series is based on. The idea for the song was initiated by screenwriter Jenny Klein, who was assigned to write the screenplay for the second episode of the show. It had been established that the episode would be the introduction of the bard Jaskier (played by Joey Batey) to Geralt of Rivia (Henry Cavill).
>
> From the Wikipedia [article on Toss a Coin to your Witcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toss_a_Coin_to_Your_Witcher)

Cannot find any further information on the other songs, keep looking. But at least some songs were created for the series without roots in the novels.

Comment: Could you edit this to reference the [source for Wikipedia](https://ew.com/tv/the-witcher-toss-a-coin-to-your-witcher-anatomy-of-a-song/) with the direct quotes? Not only are they more interesting but primary sources are always better!

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Will look at it to find the same statement in there.